# Neo4J Cypher v2 Lookup a node and a relationship that may or may not exist, return both

Tags: optimization, neo4j, cypher

I have two users:

```
CREATE (a:user {id: 1})
CREATE (b:user {id: 2})
```

Users can follow each other:

```
MATCH (a:user {id: 1}), (b:user {id: 2})
CREATE (a)-[r:FOLLOWS]->(b)
```

In order to save multiple round trips over the network I would like to lookup a user, and whether another user follows them in the same query:

```
MATCH (a:user {id: 1}), (b:user {id: 2}), (a)-[r:FOLLOWS]->(b)
RETURN a, b, r
```

But if the `FOLLOWS` relationship doesn't exist I get nothing back. Is there any way to always return the user and get a NULL for the relationship if it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 2):

[OPTIONAL MATCH](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#query-optional-match) will try to match the pattern and return nulls for those that don't exist:

```
MATCH (a:user {id: 1}), (b:user {id: 2})
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)-[r:FOLLOWS]->(b)
RETURN a, b, r
```